# How can I put a div in the middle of the page if I have more than one div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a `div` on the middle of my page (that will be hidden and only be shown in some specific cases, but it is not what I want to achieve right now).

I tried fixing it and putting a `margin: 0 auto` to put it on the middle of the page but I cannot get it. I think it has to be reference with the `position: relative` and `position: absolute` of the `div` in which it is contained the `big image div` and for that `div` respectively but I cannot change their values because I made a carousel (here I do not show it because it would extend very much the code)  that needs to be with that parameters.

Here is my code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nygppLen/) in which you can see the efect that it gives to me right now. I cannot get it out.

How can I put my red div on the middle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick fix for your problem :

```
#middleDiv {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[Your Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/nygppLen/2/)

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#leftDiv{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: green;
 z-index: 0;
}

#galery{
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: blue;
}

#centerGalery{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 75%;
}

.divImage{
 display: inline-block;
}

.divImageBig{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

.imageBig{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.imageGalery{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

#middleDiv {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
   <h1> GALERY OF IMAGES</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id = "middleDiv">
   This is a prove.
  </div>
  
  
  <div id = "leftDiv">
   <div class = "divImageBig"><img class = "imageBig" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id = "galery">
   <div id = "centerGalery">
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
    <div class = "divImage"><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div> 
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just putting the margins to 0? What it is the difference between my #middleDiv? I am a bit confused. Thanks for the code!

Comment: `margin` is `auto` not `0` :-) it's a "trick" if you will, working with `absolute` and `fixed` `position`

Comment: Sorry I mean with `right: 0`, `bottom: 0`, `left: 0` and `right: 0`. Why I have to put all these values to 0? I also tried with `margin: 0 auto;` as shown in the example but it did not work. What are the differences? Thanks for all! Your code it is what I wanted to achieve ;)

Comment: Told you, `right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 0; margin: auto; position: fixed;` just works if you have a known `height` and `width` :-). See this : http://codepen.io/sodawillow/pen/yqnaC

Comment: Thank you! You solved my doubts. Thanks again for the "trick" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/nygppLen/4/

CSS

```
#middleDiv {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it on middle of it parent , you can use:

```
#middleDiv{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position:fixed;
margin:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color: red;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nygppLen/3/).

```
#middleDiv{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I've given the `middleDiv` a `left:50%;` and `margin-left:-100px` (half the width of the div).

Comment: If you change div's width, you have to change this too : )

Comment: @sodawillow Correct, although I don't see this problem specified in the question.

Comment: I am just saying it's better to plan for future changes. Your answer is good but there are better ones. Plus I guess OP wanted vertical centering too, but that is not 100% clear.